# Dropdown lists don't work correctly with Modal Popup Extenders in newer version of Firefox

Tags: asp.net, ajax, firefox

I recently updated firefox to the latest version, 40.0.2, and have come across a problem dealing with the AJAX ModalPopupExtender and dropdown lists.

The issue is that when I open a ModalPopupExtender and try to select one of the values from the dropdown list, it does nothing.  It keeps the dropdown list open an nothing gets selected.  Furthermore, if I click and hold, it allows me to drag the Popup as if I was dragging the header.

My popups are in the following format:

```
   <ajax:ModalPopupExtender id="mpeModal" runat="server" PopupControlId="pnlModal" PopupDragHandleControlID="pnlModalHeader" />
   <asp:Panel id="pnlModal" runat="server" CssClass="modal-panel" style="display:none">
        <asp:Panel id="pnlModalHeader" runat="server">
            <uc:PopupHeader id="phModalHeader" Text="Header Text" runat="server />
        </asp:Panel>
        <div class="modal-content">
            <asp:TextBox id="txtField" runat="server" />
            <asp:DropdownList id="ddlField" runat="server />
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
```

The last version of Firefox I was using was 34, so I'm not sure if a version between 34 and 40 would have changed how this works.

Any idea what would cause this issue with Dropdown Lists in AJAX Modal Popups?

Answer (score 0):

After more testing of my app, I found a few cases where it did work correctly.

The issue was that in some cases pnlModalHeader was not present in the markup and PopupDragHandleControlID was set to pnlModal.  This is how all the old Modal Popups in the app were being done and in previous version of Firefox (and all other browsers) this caused the user to be able to drag the ModalPopup by clicking anywhere in the panel, not just the header.  I changed this, but must have missed a couple.

It now works appropriately in the newer version of Firefox.